# Integrating Google Test with Cmake Build Error : No such file or directory Error

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, googletest

Hi I am using cmake to integrate Gtest and perform a test on sample C code.
I using GCC 13.2.0 x86_64-mingw32(mingw64) and VScode.
Below I have mentioned the Directory structure and root cmakelist and sub-level cmakelist.

Directory structure:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt 
├── googletest
├── sourcecode
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── calculator.c , calculator.h           
│    
└── testSource
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── calculator_test.cpp
```

MakeLists.txt

```
        cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8) 
        set(This NAME_FOR_PROJECT) 
        project(${This} C CXX) 
        project(${This} VERSION 1.0.0)
        set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99) 
        set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON) 
        set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON) 
        set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
        set (CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON) 

        include(CTest)
        enable_testing() 

        add_subdirectory(googletest) 
        add_subdirectory(sourcecode)
        add_subdirectory(testSource)
```

sourcecode/MakeLists.txt

```
        set(This Sourcecodes)

        set(Sources
        calculator.c
        )

        set(Headers 
        calculator.h
        )
        add_library(${This}   SHARED  ${Sources}  ${Headers})
```

testSource/MakeLists.txt

```
        cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8) 
        set(This gtestSources) 

        set(Sources 
        exampletest.cpp )

        add_executable(${This} ${Sources})
        target_link_libraries(${This} PUBLIC 
        gtest_main 
        Sourcecodes
        )

        target_include_directories(${This}  PUBLIC sourcecode)
        target_link_directories(${This} PUBLIC  sourcecode) 

        add_test(
        NAME ${This}
        COMMAND ${This}
        )
```

testSource/calculator_test.cpp

```
        #include<gtest/gtest.h>
        #include<sourcecode/example.h>
        TEST(Exampletest, Exampletest_calculator){
        EXPECT_EQ(calculator('+',4,5), 9);
        EXPECT_EQ(calculator('+',4,5), 10);
        }
```

testSource/calculator.h

```
        #include<stdio.h>
        float calculator (char op, int num1, int num2);
```

After build, I  am getting error *fatal error: calculator.h: No such file or directory*

Can someone please let me know what I am missing here?

Comment: The shown code doesn't use calculator.h, please post a [mcve].

Comment: This also has nothing to do with gtest, it has to do with your include path being incorrect.  Using `This` to mean multiple things in your project is going to make it more complicated to keep track of things.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that test do see proepr include directory from `Sourcecodes` target.
To fix it you should add public incldue directory to `Sourcecodes` target:

Add to `sourcecode/CMakeLists.txt`

```cpp
target_include_directories(Sourcecodes PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

This means: add current source directory (`${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}`) as include directory of `Sourcecodes` and any target which will link `Sourcecodes` (`PUBLIC`).

For details see [doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html).

Note that in `testSource/MakeLists.txt` you've used `target_include_directories` and `target_link_directories` incorrectly, just drop them.

---

Side notes:

- this `${This}` variable is obsolete. It makes cmake code more complex without any gains.
- check how [project](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/project.html#project) should be used.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. I am still facing the issue. I have the code pasted here : https://github.com/Benjelojacob/ENVunitest